# Invalid key name

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, windows-server-2003-r2

In a quick and dirty backup script that's been running fine for years, the registry backup part no longer works. I run the offending code in the command line and get the same result:

```
C:\>reg export /y HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI test.reg
ERROR: nombre de clave no válido.
Escriba "REG EXPORT /?" para obtener detalles de uso.
```

Error translates as "invalid key name". If I lauch regedit and copy the key name to clipboard I get this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI
```

If there is a typo, I'm unable to spot it.

Am I really mistyping the key name? Is there any other reason for the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation says this:

> ```
> Reg export KeyName FileName [/y]
> ```

In other words, flags come last:

```
C:\>reg export HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI test.reg /y
La operación se ha completado correctamente.
```

No idea why it's been working before.